# encontrar escritura style="height: 293px;" dentro de mi plantilla de wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Necesito editar la altura limitada del menú...

[image: escritura]

descargue los siguientes archivos y los examine como proyecto en Atom, con su buscador...

[image: directorio de la plantilla de wordpress]
[image: buscador de atom]

**¿donde encuentro style="height: 293px;"?**

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría crear un tema hijo de tu theme de wordpress.
después, en tu nuevo archivo `CSS` añadir el estilo deseado a la clase o el ID que genera el problema.

```
    #header-responsive-inner{
        height: auto !important!;
     }
```

puedes ver cómo crear tu tema hijo en
[Crear tema hijo en Wordpress](http://programandoamimanera.com/crear-tema-hijo-wordpress-en-5-minutos/)